# Poisson Process Arrival Rate Estimation

Tags: poisson-process

Poisson Process Arrival Rate Estimation
[image]

I think we are supposed to use the fact that Poisson is memoryless but I don't understand how that helps us in calculating the arrival rate.

Comment: Likely you are intended to apply a max likelihood estimate of $\lambda$ given $X_1=2,X_2=12,X_3\geq 7$.

Comment: @Michael where to be clear, $X_i$ is the $i^{\rm th}$ interarrival time and not a counting random variable.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.